# Compress all files of certain file types in subfolders in one file per subfolder using shell script or AppleScript

Tags: shell, zip, applescript

I am looking for a way to archive all files of certain file types in one zip file per subfolder.

---

***My folder structure is as follows:***

```
/path/to
    └── TopLevel
        ├── SubLevel1
        │   ├── SubSubLevel1
        │   ├── SubSubLevel2
        │   └── SubSubLevel3
        ├── SubLevel2
        │   ├── SubSubLevel1
        │   ├── SubSubLevel2
        │   └── SubSubLevel3
        ├── SubLevel3
        │   ├── SubSubLevel1
        │   └── SubSubLevel2
        └── SubLevel4
```

---

In each folder or subfolder or sub-subfolder, there are files of the file type *.abc, *.xyz and also *.001 through *.999 and all these files I want to compress into one zip file per folder, i.e. all files of the specified types in folder "SubSubLevel1" of "SubLevel1" of "TopLevel" should be packaged into one file named "SubSubLevel1_data.zip" inside the "SubSubLevel1" folder. All other files in these folders, which do not match the search criteria as described above, should be kept unzipped in the same directory.

I have found some ideas [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496432/gzip-all-files-with-specific-extensions) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104208/how-to-zip-recursively-all-subdirectories-that-only-contain-text-files), but both approaches are based on a different way of archiving the files and I have so far not found a way to adopt them to my needs since I am not very experienced with shell scripting. I have also tried to get a solution with AppleScript, but there I face the problem how to get all files in the folder with the number as an extension (*.001 through *.999). With RegEx, I would do something like ".abc|.xyz.\d\d\d" which would cover my search for certain file types, but I am also not sure now how to implement the result of a grep in AppleScript.

I guess someone out there must have an idea how to address my archiving issue. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around I came up with the following solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

find -E "$PWD" -type d -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*201[0-5][0-1][0-9].*" -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" thisFolder ; do
  echo "The current folder is: $thisFolder"
  to_archive=( "$thisFolder"/*.[Aa][Bb][Cc] "$thisFolder"/*.[Xx][Yy][Zz] "$thisFolder"/*.[0-9][0-9][0-9] )

  if [ ${#to_archive[@]} != 0 ]
  then
    7z a -mx=9 -uz1 -x!.DS_Store "$thisFolder"/"${thisFolder##*/}"_data.7z "${to_archive[@]}" && rm "${to_archive[@]}"
  fi

  find "$thisFolder" -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" thisSubFolder ; do
    echo "The current subfolder is: $thisSubFolder"
    to_archive=( "$thisSubFolder"/*.[Aa][Bb][Cc] "$thisSubFolder"/*.[Xx][Yy][Zz] "$thisSubFolder"/*.[0-9][0-9][0-9] )

    if [ ${#to_archive[@]} != 0 ]
    then
      7z a -mx=9 -uz1 -x!.DS_Store "$thisSubFolder"/"${thisSubFolder##*/}"_data.7z "${to_archive[@]}" && rm "${to_archive[@]}"
    fi
  done
 done
```

My script has two nested for loops to iterate through subfolders and sub-subfolders. With "find" I look for a regex pattern in order to only backup folders from 2010-2015 . All files matching the specified extensions inside the folders are compressed in one target archive per folder.